# how to add a new row with extra column in R?

Tags: r, rbind

I was trying to add results of a for loop into a dataframe as new rows, but it gets an error when there is a new result with more columns than the original dataframe, how could I add the new result with extra columns to the dataframe with adding the extra column names to the original dataframe?

e.g.
original dataframe:

-______A B C

- x1 1 1 1
- x2 2 2 2
- x3 3 3 3

I want to get

-______A B C D

- x1 1 1 1 NA
- x2 2 2 2 NA
- x3 3 3 3 NA
- X4 4 4 4 4

I tried rbind (Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) :
numbers of columns of arguments do not match)
and rbind_fill (Error: All inputs to rbind.fill must be data.frames)
and bind_rows (Argument 2 must have names)

Answer (score 3):

In `base R`, this can be done by creating a new column 'D' with `NA` and then assign new row with 4.

```
df1$D <- NA
df1['x4', ] <- 4
```

-output

```
> df1
   A B C  D
x1 1 1 1 NA
x2 2 2 2 NA
x3 3 3 3 NA
x4 4 4 4  4
```

---

Or in a single line

```
rbind(cbind(df1, D = NA), x4 = 4)
   A B C  D
x1 1 1 1 NA
x2 2 2 2 NA
x3 3 3 3 NA
x4 4 4 4  4
```

---

Regarding the error in `bind_rows`, it happens when the `for` loop output is not a named vector

```
library(dplyr)
> vec1 <- c(4, 4, 4, 4)
> bind_rows(df1, vec1)
Error: Argument 2 must have names.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

If it is a named vector, then it should work

```
> vec1 <- c(A = 4, B = 4, C = 4, D = 4)
> bind_rows(df1, vec1)
     A B C  D
x1   1 1 1 NA
x2   2 2 2 NA
x3   3 3 3 NA
...4 4 4 4  4
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(A = 1:3, B = 1:3, C = 1:3), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("x1", 
"x2", "x3"))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment, but this is just a simplified sample. The new rows to combine actually comes from the results of a for loop and there could be multiple new rows with extra columns to be added so is there a way to let it automatically add the extra column names according to the for loop output?

Comment: @Kleos It is better to show the structure of new row getting added.  Is it a data.frame or vector or something else?

Comment: @Kleos Does it have the row name 'x4' or it should be decided from the original dataset?

Comment: @Kleos Try with `df1 <- dplyr::bind_rows(df1, yourobject_from_loop)`

Comment: @Kleos Based on the error you are getting, it seems that you have a `vector` i.e. you may need to convert to `data.frame` or a `list` i.e. `df1 <- dplyr::bind_rows(df1, as.list(yourvec))`

Comment: Hi! Yes, I also tried data.frame and it worked. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You probably have something like this, if you `list` the elements of your `for` loop.

```
(l <- list(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5))
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 1 1
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 2 2 2 2
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 3 3
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] 4
# 
# [[5]]
# NULL
```

Multiple elements can be `rbind`ed using a `do.call(rbind, .)` approach, your problem is, how to `rbind` multiple elements that differ in `length`.

There's a `` `length<-` `` function with which you may adjust the length of a vector. To know to which length, there's another function, `lengths`, that gives you the lengths of each list element, where you are interested in the `max`imum.

I include the special case when an element has length `NULL` (our 5<sup>th</sup> element of `l`); since length of NULL cannot be changed, `replace` those elements with `NA`.

So altogether you may do:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(replace(l, lengths(l) == 0L, NA), `length<-`, max(lengths(l))))
#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    1    1   NA
# [2,]    2    2    2    2
# [3,]    3    3   NA   NA
# [4,]    4   NA   NA   NA
# [5,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

Or, since you probably want a data frame with pretty row and column names:

```
ml <- max(lengths(l))
do.call(rbind, lapply(replace(l, lengths(l) == 0L, NA), `length<-`, ml)) |>
  as.data.frame() |> `dimnames<-`(list(paste0('x', 1:length(l)), LETTERS[1:ml]))
#     A  B  C  D
# x1  1  1  1 NA
# x2  2  2  2  2
# x3  3  3 NA NA
# x4  4 NA NA NA
# x5 NA NA NA NA
```

**Note:** R >= 4.1 used.

---

*Data:*

```
x1 <- rep(1, 3); x2 <- rep(2, 4); x3 <- rep(3, 2); x4 <- rep(4, 1); x5 <- NULL
```